# Due to the quarantine is it mandatory to shower on Friday?

Tags: halal-haram, sunnah, ghusl, jumuah

I have the following question: Many countries are now in quarantine due to the coronavirus. School and masajids are closed. No one can do the Friday prayer. Is it mandatory to shower on Friday? I thought it was because but now that know one can go to the Friday prayer...

Comment: No, rather you can walk around with stinky armpits because cleanliness is half of our Emaan.

Comment: There's a difference of opinion between scholars some scholar consider it sunnah to perform ghusl for the prayer others consider the ghusl sunnah as due to celebrate the day itself. In either case ghusl isn't mandatory. See [Can someone do ghusl after Maghrib on Thursday for Jumu'ah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/48573/13438)

Answer (score 4):

Some say that ghusl on Friday is obligatory, some say it is recommended, but nevertheless:

> [Al-Bayhaqi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Bayhaqi) narrates:
>
> Ibn `Umar reported that the Prophet (peace be upon him) said, “Men and women coming for the Friday prayer should take a bath, but **those who aren’t, shouldn’t.**”
>
> <sup>- Nihayat Al-Muhtaj</sup>

The main purpose of performing ghusl on Friday is to purify oneself for the Jummuah salah, because Friday is the most blessed day of the week. Quite a lot of scholars say it is highly recommended (part of Sunnah) to perform ghusl on Friday and some say it is mandatory.

But as per the hadith you don't have to shower on Friday since you are not attending the Jummuah congregation.